# AIC for comparing normal linear models

Tags: regression, self-study, model-selection, aic, sums-of-squares

I know that for a normal linear model that has $p+1$ parameters (call it $M_1$), and has $\hat{\sigma} = [\Sigma(y_i - \hat{\mu_i)^2]/n}]$, then the AIC (from wikipedia) is:

$AIC = n[log(2\pi \hat{\sigma}^2) + 1] + 2(p+ 1)$

Now I have another model, call it $M_2$, which has $q$ additional terms. I need to determine if M_2 will have a smaller AIC if we know that $SSE_2/SSE_1 < e^{-2q/n}$.

I'm sort of stumped on this. I suspect that the AIC for $M_2$ will be *smaller*, but I wasn't able to obtain an expression that actually shows this is the case. Does anybody see how I show this? I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is this an exercise for some class?

Comment: Not homework, but I'm doing some problems on model selection to study for an exam, so technically yes?

Comment: We would usually call such a question self-study and offer hints and guidance if you can show a good attempt. Could you add the `self-study` tag (you'd need to replace one of your current five; I'd suggest either model-selection or generalized-linear-model could be replaced). You might like to write down how how $\hat{\sigma}^2$ relates to SSE and then write the difference in AIC for the two models (AIC2-AIC1), which will be <0 if the AIC for M2 is smaller. Then see if you can manipulate that inequality. Playing with that should give you more of a sense of the direction to head.

Comment: Eventually you'll be exponentiating to get a ratio rather than a difference (or going the other way, you'll take the logs of the ratio to take the last expression toward a difference in AICs). Once you see how they connect you should be able to arrange it into a proper derivation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it was obvious after setting up the inequality you suggested! I'll accept it as an answer if you post as one :)

Comment: you should feel free to post an answer yourself, but if you don't I'll try to post something soon